# Can we have a page that lets us show off a specific badge we've earned?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, badges, social-networking, sharing

Is there a way to share a link to an SO page which says that I got awarded a badge?  I'm kinda proud of one I just got so I'd like to post about it on social networks like Twitter / Facebook.  But I can't find a public URL to a page saying "__ user got __ badge on __ date because they were __ awesome."

Does such a page exist?  If not, should we make one?

This page https://stackoverflow.com/badges/298/javascript?userid=303056 is close, but misses what I'm looking for in the following ways:

- Doesn't name the user
- Doesn't include date awarded  (Less important)
- Doesn't confirm that the userid in the querystring actually got the award

Comment: Like your badges page, sorted by recent? http://stackoverflow.com/users/303056/leopd?tab=badges&sort=recent

Comment: Eh, seems like a lot of work for something which won't get much use. To be honest, you could also just post on twitter, "I just got __ badge!" and it would have the same effect.

Comment: The page with all badges isn't something I'd share or crow about b/c it is a laundry list, not a specific accomplishment.  Given that a similar page exists, I don't think it would be much work.  I leave it to the community to judge how often people would do this.  As for just tweeting the accomplishment in text, SO should want its users driving traffic into the site.

Comment: I'm not sure why this would get downvoted. It seems like the kind of thing people would either use or not care about at all.

Comment: More exposure to the site, and expanding the gamification rewards with relatively low cost both seem like good things to me.  The only reasons I could see to not do this is if the pool of users who would actually use it would be too low to be worth creating the page - though, admittedly the sort of people driven to the site by a "check out my awesome badge" post on facebook are unlikely to be experts in the field.

Comment: @BilltheLizard - This seems to change the focus from questions and answers to "Look what I did!". Not exactly in the Stack Overflow spirit.

Comment: @BoPersson I see very little difference between this and displaying your top tags on your Careers profile. Even less difference between this and [flair](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1288/bill-the-lizard/flair). People post those in their profile, on their blogs, and on social networks all the time. That doesn't change the focus of Stack Overflow at all.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think the problem is that for badges that *can't* be awarded multiple times, there's no guarantee your name will be noticeable in the big list of users.

For badges that *are* awarded multiple times, the situation is already pretty good - [you get your name in the header, a nice list of dates when you were awarded the badge](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/27/notable-question?userid=303056), and no one else is shown.

If normal badges also started off with,

> ### Leopd earned this badge on April 12, 2013:
>
> #### <kbd>javascript</kbd> Earned 100 upvotes for at least 20 answers in the javascript tag.

...it'd be a whole lot more impressive of a link to pass around.

### Update: completion

With the recent badge redesign, this situation appears much improved:

[image: JavaScript tag-badge page]

I'm marking this completed - please thank [Jeremy Tunnell](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/202998/jeremy-tunnell) and [Sklivvz](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/131112/sklivvz) for the work here!